# How many solutions are there to a matrix over a finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix of the form `Ax=b` of arbitrary dimensions, which is defined over a finite field Z with p elements (p being a prime number), how many solutions can the matrix have?

A matrix which is defined over R (all reals, infinite field) may have infinite solutions. This is impossible with a finite field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(EDITED) 
Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix over your field $\mathbb F$.  In the case $A = 0$, $b=0$, all members of $\mathbb F^n$ are solutions, and there are $p^n$ of them.  If $A$ has rank $r$, the solutions (if any) form an affine subspace of dimension $n-r$, so there are $p^{n-r}$ solutions if there are any.

Comment: I edited my question. I'm looking for `Ax=b` where `A` is a matrix of any dimensions.

Comment: I think the important point for the OP is that the set of solutions (the kernel) is a subspace. If the field is infinite then the subspace isn't. If the field is finite then the kernel must be finite. Solutions to the inhomogenous equation are just translates of the kernel.

Comment: ... English? What's a matrix rank? What's a linear subspace?

Comment: These are standard terms in linear algebra.  [linear subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace), [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, such a matrix can have `p` to the power of `n` solutions, where `n` is the amount of free variables in the matrix.

Comment: That is precisely what @Robert Isreal said

Comment: Aha, good to know. Looks to me like two separate languages right now.